# Hive exits after JDBC query

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am using `Hive shipped with Cloudera version 5.3.1` which is exiting at random after every `5-6 days`. The issue started only after querying the `DB from Java`. Following are the queries executed via Java:

```
 1. Truncate Table
 2. Load data into Table
 3. simple Select query with where clause
```

The crash is always accompanied by following warning message:

```
WARN Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
```

So my question is

```
1. Shouldn't `hive jdbc driver` implement tool runner by itself? 
2. Moreover why is hive crashing randomly if tool-runner is not implemented?
```

Edit: I am using `OpeCsv2.3 SerDe`.

Comment: This is just a warning and is pretty normal. Why do you think it's a crash? Do you see any errors on the client side or just query does not return anything? Do you see issues in the HiveServer/HiveServer2 logs?

Comment: There is no error in any log file, Hive Server process simply exits after the warning everytime. Client side get connection failure exception. I will paste the exception here shortly.